# Cannot resolve com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-layout, parse-platform

My current setup :

- OS : windows 7
- IDE : Android Studio (with updated SDKs)
- Parse jar (v 1.10)

I am trying out an example for ParseQueryAdapter, and I run into this error on my IDE : `import com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter;` -> `cannot resolve symbol ParseQueryAdapter`

I want to try something similar to this [example](https://parse.com/tutorials/parse-query-adapter), and the `import` does not seem to go through because of the error.

If you need anymore information, please leave comments & I will respond.

**PS :** I am able to add `com.parse.ParseObject` without errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your libs folder you'll find Parse-1.4.1.jar file.
Right click or control+click on it then 'Add as Library...'

Edit: Parse-1.10 does not have ParseQueryAdapter. You have to use Parse-1.4.1, which is included in that example.

Comment: i was able to add the library successfully - only when i try to import `com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter` - i get this issue.

Comment: from what i observe parse1.10(ten), doesnt have the ParseQueryAdapter. Is this deprecated?

Comment: com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter removed from library.

Comment: Did the parse team release any official notice of this deprecation? Because my application rely heavily on this....

Answer (score 3):

ParseQueryAdapter was removed from the official Parse SDK and moved onto the Parse-UI libraries..

You can install them on via this link: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android

Answer (score 0):

If we include 1.4.1, and keep 1.10.1 as well, it gives error because we cannot keep the same jar with two versions in the libs folder. And I think its not advisable to use just 1.4.1. I feel that ParseQueryAdapter is deprecated and we would just have to use the normal adapters. Any comments?